# JPEG Decompression in Android

Tags: android, jpeg, decoder

I am developing an Android application that would stream a set of jpeg images over the internet. I need to decode each jpeg image into YUV format, perform some image related operations and then stream it after performing some encoding. Currently I am performing this conversion [JPEG -> YUV] in software. To speed up this conversion, I would like to use hardware decoders. Is there is any Android API that can do this coversion ? Can this be done using OMXCodec?

Regards,

John

Comment: Why did you remove the texts that were quoted by CW? Makes it all unclear.

Comment: Ha ha... I thought it was CW. But it was AD. Sorry.